# Place # symbol after blank space while typing in an EditText

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm working in a project in which we have to add only hashtags e.g. #mytag1 #mytag2 etc. I want that whenever user presses space button it will automatically add # after the spcae.
Here is what i tried (but doing that app becomes not responding).

```
tagsEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                String a = s.toString().replace(" ", " #");
                tagsEt.setText(a);
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {


            }
        });
```

Comment: App is not responding because it will start an endless loop when you enter character onTextChanged will be called it will change text in edit text and due to this change again onTextChanged will be called, and this process will continue endlessly.

Comment: do the following in `afterTextChanged`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution. I've commented on most parts of code so you can understand easily.

```
/*To place a # symbol after a blank space while typing in tags input field*/
InputFilter inputFilter = new InputFilter() {

    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
            //get currently typed character
            char currentChar = source.charAt(i);
            //check if it typed character was a blank space or not
            if (currentChar == ' ') {
                //typed character is a blank space, add space and #
                builder.append(currentChar);
                builder.append('#');
            } else {
                //typed character is not a blank space, add the character as it is
                builder.append(currentChar);
            }

        }
        return builder.toString();
    }

};
tagsEt.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{inputFilter});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should get the whole text trim and check the last character, like this

```
    if (s.toString().trim().charAt(s.length() - 1) == ' ') {
        // do the job here
    }
```

Comment: i need to add # symbol after blank space while typing. My code works perfect but when i try to set it on my edit text app goes not responding.